# If a function maps $A$ to its PowerSet, is it Surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given an arbitrary set $A$, let $F : A \rightarrow 2^A$ be the function defined for
all $a \in A$ by

$f(a) = \{a\}$

If $A$ maps to its power set, does this make $F$ surjective?

If somebody could help to prove this that would be very helpful

Comment: Have you looked at a basic example, like $A = \{1,2\}$?

Comment: I read somewhere that, No matter what A is, the EmptySet is an element of the PowerSet, so it cannot be onto, but I dont understand why

Comment: Then you need to read more about what a "power set" is, and probably what it takes for a function to be "onto"/surjective.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not surjective because $ \emptyset $ is not in the range of $f$

Comment: Just to clarify, where did you get the range of f from?

Comment: the range of $f$ is the set of all elements $y$ such that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$, we define it as follow $$Range(f)=f(A)=\{f(x)/x\in A\} $$ and $f$ is surjective if and only if every element is in $f(A)$

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* surjective map from $A \to 2^A$ as [Cantor has taught us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem) with [his diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no $x$ for which $f(x)=\emptyset$. Surjective means it hits everything in $2^A$ which it doesn't because $\emptyset \in 2^A$.

$f$ is injective though.

Comment: for any type of powerset question similar to above, would this hold?

Comment: If there was an X for which F(x) = EmptySet, this would make it surjective right?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is in any powerset.

Comment: You have to hit everything. If there is a surjection between $A$ and $2^A$ then $|A| \geq |2^A|$, which can never be true. For finite sets, it's true because $2^n > n$, and for infinite sets it follows by Cantor's theorem. There is no such surjection.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume $A$ itself is non-empty so the proposed mapping $f$ has non-empty image. *Elements* of the power set of $A$ are *subsets* of $A$. The power set therefore comprises the empty set, "singleton" sets containing exactly one element, sets containing two elements, or three, etc.; if $A$ itself contains infinitely many elements, then $A$ also has subsets containing infinitely many elements, and each is an element of the power set.

In order for a function with codomain $2^{A}$ to be surjective, *every subset of $A$ must be in the image*.

The image of the mapping $f(a) = \{a\}$ consists of the singleton subsets of $A$. Not every subset of $A$ is a singleton, so $f$ is not surjective.

Perhaps you're conflating the image of $f$ with the union
$$
\bigcup_{a \in A} f(a) = \bigcup_{a \in A} \{a\} = A?
$$